# SpringMVC: display error view on failed AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, error-handling

I have a web page that, on a user query, makes a request to the service and renders the HTML table (so not the whole page) on itself with the data it received from **AJAX**.

There is 2 ways for calling the service:

1. **Through API**: my.website.com/api/person/John --> this returns a raw JSON
2. **AJAX request**: my.website.com/person#John --> internally this calls the API, and fills the HTML table with the data it gest

The thing that is happening is that if the `internal error` occurs:

1. when calling **through API**: my custom error view gets displayed - this the desired behaviour
2. whenn calling with **AJAX request**: custom error view does NOT get displayed - instead all that happens is that the HTML table doesn't get filled - bad behaviour. I want error view here, too!

*javascript*

```
function displayPersonData(template, person) {
        var url = "/api/person/" + person;

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            renderHtmlTable(template, data);
        });
}
```

*APIcontroller.java*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/person/{person}", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person execute(@PathVariable(value = "person") String person) {

        Random r = new Random();
        if(r.nextDouble() > 0.5) {
            return proxy.getPersonData(person); // returns JSON
        } else {
            throw new MyCustomException("Test");
        }       
}
```

*Error Controller.java*

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public ModelAndView errorCallingService() {
    LOG.error(MessageFormat.format("Call to %s failed.", PERSON_SERVICE)); // the logs gets triggered successfuly

    return new ModelAndView("error_view.jsp"); // error_view doesnt get displayed
}
```

The error controller gets triggered successfully the thrown Exception, and it generates the log. But from some reason it doesn't display the `error_view.jsp`. Only when called with AJAX.

Is there a solution? And I don't want redirection to error page, it just doesn't seem right to have URL like: my.website.com/exception_view

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that ajax request will give you response as text, not redirect. So you should handle view rendering by yourself. 
But currently you most likely don't even get text respnse from server because of:

- if your error view name is "error_view.jsp" than spring will try to find view at "/api/person/error_view.jsp". In this case change return value to "/error_view.jsp" to prevent relative path creation.
- Another point is that $.getJSON will probably produce error on client side, because in case of error the response content type is text/html. Use $.ajax instead.
- Lastly HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR will cause your request to fail so you need to register another callback for error.

To handle returned html you can put it to a predefined placeholder on page. So the code can be look like this in js:

```
function displayPersonData(template, person) {
    var url = "/api/person/" + person;

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function (data) {
        renderHtmlTable(template, data);
      },
      error: function (xhr) {
        $("#placeholder").html(xhr.responseText);
      },
    );
}
```